# How to modify dock transparency in gnome?

Tags: gnome

I copied the files /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css of a friend of mine, who set the transparency to the maximum.

I want to change it, to make it less transparent.

Which option should I modify?

[image]

Comment: Can you link to an upload of the CSS file?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/S8gP167b thx! :)

Comment: Can you try this one and tell me if it worked? There are a few possibilities, and I want to go through them one by one. http://pastebin.com/u9zWD253

Comment: Wow! It works! But how did you find the point to be changed?

Comment: This is the section of code I changed: `/* DASHBOARD */
#dash {
    font-size: 9pt;
    color: #eeeeec;
    background-color: rgba(30,30,30,0.4);
    padding: 4px 0;
    border: 0px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.4);
    border-left: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px; }`. I changed the `background-color` field to a dark gray color. I'll put it in as an answer, do the formatting is better.

Answer (score 1):

To change the launcher transparency, find this section in the CSS file:

```
/* DASHBOARD */
#dash {
font-size: 9pt;
color: #eeeeec;
background-color: rgba(30,30,30,0.4);
padding: 4px 0;
border: 0px solid rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.4);
border-left: 0px;
border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px; }
```

Change the `background-color` field to whatever you want. I used the RGBA format, so that transparency would work. The format of what I used is:

```
rgba(RED 0-255, GREEN 0-255, BLUE 0-255, OPACITY 0.0-1.0)
```

If the opacity is `1.0` it will be completely opaque.

***EDITS:***

To make the borders on the shutdown dialog buttons rounded, you need to add this somewhere in the CSS file (it doesn't really matter, but if you want organization, put it under the `/* Restart */` header):

```
.end-session-dialog .modal-dialog-button,
.end-session-dialog .modal-dialog-linked-button {
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 10px; }
```

Change the `width` and `height` sections to what you think looks good.

Comment: Thanks, thanks, thanks! Can I ask you the last question? You have no idea how to change the gnome-shell.css files, so the green border - red - white being rounded? This is the image: http://i.imgur.com/zj7V7CQ.png

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. Give me a bit and I'll see if I can find that.

Comment: That's the power menu, right?

Comment: See if this works. I've kept the dock transparency change. http://pastebin.com/NNBruTkv

Comment: Amazing, it works! I could ask you to increase the size of the 3 'circles' colored?
I swear that after you no more trouble :P

Comment: Can I see a screenshot of what it looks like currently?

Comment: Sure: http://i.imgur.com/Wwfhk4Q.png

Comment: OK. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thx Zacharee...

Comment: OK. I put the code you need in my answer. Search for `/* Restart */` and add in the `width` and `height` fields into the matching area.